# On the exponential function.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, summation, exponential-function

I was rereading the prologue to *Real and Complex Analysis* by Rudin (in image) and I realized I never really understood why we have

[image]

the first and second equality after$\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{a^k}{k!}\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}\frac{b^m}{m!} $ and where does the absolute convergence of (1) play a role.

So could somebody provide some extra steps and maybe I will understand?

Comment: You need absolute convergence to be sure that the change in the order of summation is legal.

Answer (score 1):

This first and second formula are nothing but
$$
(1+a+{a^2\over2}+...)(1+b+{b^2\over2}+...)
=1\times1+a\times1+1\times b+a\times b+1\times{b^2\over2}+{a^2\over2}\times1\\
=1+(a+b)+{(a+b)^2\over2}+...\\
$$
The
$$
\sum{1\over n!}\sum{n!\over(n-k)!k!}
$$
uses $n!/n!=1$ to get an $n\choose k$ in the sum to show that the coefficients of $a^k b^{n-k}$ are the binomial expansion of $(a+b)^n$.

A proof that absolute convergence allows the summations to be exchanged can be found online [here](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Efeldman/m321/twosum.pdf). The proof is quite long so I won't copy it all out here. It relies on another theorem which I wasn't able to locate at that web site.

The author also constructs a counterexample of a series which converges, but not absolutely, and shows that the order of summation affects the limit value.

Comment: Formally writing $(a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + \ldots)(b_0 + b_1 + b_2 + \ldots) = a_0 b_0 +(a_1b_0 + a_0 b_1 ) + (a_0 b_2 + a_1b_1 + a_2b_0) + \ldots$ does not prove that the series on the RHS converges.  This is the Cauchy product $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \sum_{n= 0}^\infty = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k}$ where the series converges on the right side if at least one series on the left side converges absolutely. See [Mertens' theorem](https://second.wiki/wiki/satz_von_mertens_cauchy-produkt).

Comment: Foe example if both series on the left side converge conditionally, then the Cauchy product series on the right side may not converge.

Comment: I've given a link to the proof about absolute convergence in the question and it was also mentioned in the comment under the question seven years ago. In the link there is also a counterexample where the author constructs a demonstration of a series which converges but not absolutely and shows that the order of summation affects the limit value. There is a lot of information at the link, and the proof relies on other results, so I did not copy it all into this answer.

Comment: Your link discusses  absolute convergence and justifying interchanging the order of iterated infinite series as in $\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_{mn} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty x_{mn}$.  What does that have to do with proving the convergence of the convolution $\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k$ where $c_k = a_i b_{k-i}$ and the equality $\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k= \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i \cdot \sum_{j=0}^\infty b_j$?  Again -- that is what this question is really about.

Comment: The title of this question is "On the exponential function" and we are given in the text a quote which notes that the power series for the function converges absolutely. Please also note that the text at the link is not mine, I am not Joel Feldman.